# Print statement within a loop

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, printf

I have few text files named as file1.txt, file2.txt and so on.
I would like to print the mean of each file after giving some weightage to it. My script is

```
#!/bin/sh
m1=3.2; m2=1.2; m3=0.2   #mean of file1.txt, file2.txt ...
for i in {1..100}   #files
  do for j in 20 30 35 45   #weightages 
    do
      k=m$i*$j  #This is an example, calulated as mean of file$i.txt * j
      printf "%5s %8.3f\n" "$i" "$k" >> ofile.txt
    done
  done
```

The above it printing as

```
ofile.txt
1    64
1    96
1    112
1    144
2    24
2    36
.    .
```

Desire output format as

```
ofile.txt
1    64   96   112   144
2    24   36   42    54
3    4    6    7     9
.     .    .    .     .
```

where 1st column is the file numbers, 2nd, 3rd, 4th columns are m*j

Comment: Your format string is for pairs of numbers. So that's what you get. If you want different output use a different format string (or set of format strings). A format string doesn't need to end with a newline and `printf` will repeat the format string for all its arguments (try `printf %s\\n a b c d` for example).

Comment: Just put printf $i at the start of outer loop and printf \n at the end of the outer loop. Of course, you will have to also remove the $i and \n in the inner loop printf statement

Comment: Yes, Thank you. But I can't able to modify the print statement to get my desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head so you might need to correct some stuff.

```
#!/bin/sh
m1=3.2; m2=1.2; m3=0.2   #mean of file1.txt, file2.txt ...
for i in {1..100}   #files
  do
    printf "%5s" "$i" >> ofile.txt
    for j in 20 30 35 45   #weightages 
      do
        k=m$i*$j  #This is an example, calulated as mean of file$i.txt * j
        printf "\t%8.3f" "$k" >> ofile.txt
      done
    printf "\n" >> ofile.txt
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
m1=3.2; m2=1.2; m3=0.2   #mean of file1.txt, file2.txt ...
for i in {1..100}   #files
  ofile_line="$i "
  do for j in 20 30 35 45   #weightages 
    do
      k=m$i*$j  #This is an example, calulated as mean of file$i.txt * j
      support=$(printf "%5s %8.3f\n" "$i" "$k")
      ofile_line="${ofile_line}${support} "
    done
   echo "${ofile_line}" >> ofile.txt
  done
```

You don't need a `\n` in echo `"${ofile_line}" >> ofile.txt` because `echo` breaks the line for you.